# xsl prevent url escaping

Tags: xml, image, xslt

I have a problem with xsl.

I want to generate an img with a url to a php file that does a database request for the picture (mongoDb).

This is the XML:

```
<source>getPicture.php?filename=CIMG8175.JPG" name="CIMG8175.JPG" id="548cd10f090e66c81a000049" onclick="getPictureAttribut(this)</source>
```

This is my xsl at the moment:

```
<img>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('',source)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

And this is what I get:

```
src="getPicture.php?filename=CIMG8175.JPG%22%20name=%22CIMG8175.JPG%22%20id=%22548cd10f090e66c81a000049%22%20onclick=%22getPictureAttribut(this)"
```

How do I disable all these %22%20 rewriting?

I tried in SOOO many ways but I can`t figure it out :(

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: What does your expected output look like? Attribute values that are delimited by double quotes cannot contain double quotes.

Comment: Are you sure it's a *problem*, or are you only worried that a computer may not be able to correctly read it because you can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the src was one big link... but it has to be like:

```
src="somePath" name="someName" onclick"getSomething(this)"
```

I thought I could put everything I need in ONE xsl:Attribute Tag but know I give all the attributes to the img step by step.

Thanks Anayway :)

Comment: It seems you have self-answered all of your questions so far - which is a good thing! Please also [**self-accept your answers**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) to settle the issues.

Comment: Also, bear in mind even if you come up with an answer yourself, there's always the possibility others might have a better one, or offer comments/advice on yours, so check back. Incidentally, `disable-output-escaping` should NEVER be used- it's not always supported, and if you're using it, I can almost guarantee you're doing something wrong.